# Cannot use mkdir in home directory: permission denied (Linux Lubuntu)

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a directory in my home directory on Linux using the mkdir command, but am getting a 'permission denied' error.  I have recently installed Lubuntu on my laptop, and have the only user profile on the computer.

Here's what happened on my command line:

```
jdub@Snowball:~$ cd /home
jdub@Snowball:/home$ mkdir bin
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘bin’: Permission denied
jdub@Snowball:/home$
```

How do I gain access to this folder?  I am trying to write a script and following a tutorial here: http://linuxcommand.org/wss0010.php

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `/home` isn't your home directory; it's a folder that contains everyone's home directories. Your home directory is `/home/my_user_name`; you can also simply use `~`, which bash expands to your home directory.

Comment: All of sudden I am facing that permission denied issue. I simply run this script and it started working.`sudo chown -R ec2-user ~/my-path`

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As @kirbyfan64sos notes in a comment, **`/home` is NOT your home directory** (a.k.a. home folder):

The fact that `/home` is an *absolute, literal* path that *has no user-specific component* provides a clue.

While `/home` happens to be the *parent* directory of *all* user-specific home directories on Linux-based systems, you shouldn't even rely on that, given that this differs across platforms: for instance, the equivalent directory on macOS is `/Users`.

What **all Unix platforms DO have in common** are the following ways to navigate to / refer to your home directory:

- **Using `cd` with NO argument** *changes to* your home dir., i.e., makes your home dir. the *working directory*.

  - e.g.: `cd # changes to home dir; e.g., '/home/jdoe'`

- ***Unquoted* `~` by itself / *unquoted* `~/` at the start of a path string** represents your home dir. / a path starting at your home dir.; this is referred to as *tilde expansion* (see `man bash`)

  - e.g.: `echo ~ # outputs, e.g., '/home/jdoe'`

- **`$HOME` - as part of either unquoted or preferably a *double-quoted* string - refers to your home dir.** `HOME` is a predefined, user-specific *environment variable*:

  - e.g.: `cd "$HOME/tmp" # changes to your personal folder for temp. files`

---

Thus, to create the desired folder, you could use:

```
mkdir "$HOME/bin"  # same as: mkdir ~/bin
```

Note that most locations *outside* your home dir. require *superuser* (root user) privileges in order to create files or directories - that's why you ran into the `Permission denied` error.

Comment: All of sudden I am facing that permission denied issue. I simply run this script and it started working.`sudo chown -R ec2-user ~/my-path`

Answer (score 25):

you can try writing the command using 'sudo':

> sudo mkdir DirName

Comment: Not good if you intend to run automated scripts later that require permissions, it will force you to use `sudo` later on in instances in which it may be problematic.

Comment: @AmyPellegrini Once you use `sudo` to create directory, you can then use `chown -R` to change ownership to yourself. This will solve the problem of permission.

Comment: merci! best solution! always works!

Answer (score -3):

Try running fuser command

```
[root@guest2 ~]# fuser -mv /home

USER PID ACCESS COMMAND

/home: root 2919 f.... automount

[root@guest2 ~]# kill -9 2919
```

`autofs` service is known to cause this issue.

You can use command

`#service autofs stop`

And try again.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, and is poor advice.